How string literals are stored in String Constant Pool ? Why isn't "Hello " + world in the string constant pool?
Java Code

class Other {
    static String hello = "Hello World";
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        String hello = "Hello World", world = "World";

        System.out.println(Other.hello == hello);                   // Line1
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hello " + "World"));          // Line2
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hello " + world));            // Line3
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hello " + world).intern());   // Line4

        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(hello.hashCode()));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(("Hello " + "World").hashCode()));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(("Hello " + world).hashCode()));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(("Hello " + world).intern().hashCode()));
    }
     
}


I expect Line3 to return true but it is returning false. Kindly help me.
Output
true true false true
42628b2 42628b2 42628b2 42628b2

"I expect Line3 to return true" - why do you expect that?

Because as you can see the hashcode for all the four string forms are same. It means "Hello " + world is also in the SCP as in the Line2 - "Hello " + "World".

Hint: use x.equals(y) rather than x == y, unless you actually intend to compare references for identity. Closing as a duplicate now, as I'm pretty convinced the other question will resolve your misunderstanding.

No No, not a duplicate. If you read this problem I guess you will understand the problem. Please do if you are willing to help me!

I am comparing the references indeed. My question is why the Line3 is not in String Constant Pool although it is same as what written in Line2. Both the intermediate strings are created the same way!

BTW the compiler does compile "Hello " + "World" as "Hello World"; on the other side "Hello " + world is not a literal, it is an expression (if you had final String world = "World"; then the compiler would compile it as a literal and hello == ("Hello " + world) would result in true)

BTW2 there is no "String constant pool" (often seen, but confusing) - there is the "constant pool" as part of a class file (not relevant for this question); and there is the string pool of the String class (see javadoc of the String#intern method) ||| seems like a common question : Java String Constant Pool Confused - asked less than 24 hours ago

"My question is why the Line3 is not in String Constant Pool" - then that's what you should have asked. The hash code is related to value equality, not reference identity. If you already understand that hello.equals("Hello " + world") then surely you'd expect the hash codes to be the same anyway...

Only string constants are automatically stored in the String Constant Pool.
The following is a string constant because it is a literal:
"Hello " + "world"

This is specifically stated in the Java Language Specification:

A long string literal can always be broken up into shorter pieces and
written as a (possibly parenthesized) expression using the string
concatenation operator +

The following is also a string constant:
final String world = "world";
"Hello " + world

This is because world is a final variable and is therefore treated as a constant expression, and the + operator between constant expressions results in a constant expression.
The following is not a string constant:
String world = "world";
"Hello " + world

The compiler doesn't treat the string world as a constant expression as it's not declared as final, even though the compiler could have detected that its value is "effectively constant".
